# How can I remove the 'Update Strategy: No Reboots' message on CoreOS/Container Linux?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I am running a Kubernetes cluster on CoreOS and using [coreos/container-linux-update-operator](https://github.com/coreos/container-linux-update-operator) to update each node in a controlled way. When I `ssh` into one of the nodes however I am getting the message `Update Strategy: No Reboots`, presumably because I have disabled and masked `locksmithd.service` (as it is no longer needed).

How can I stop that message from appearing? It isn't actually true since `update-operator` is handling updates instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is generated when `/etc/profile.d/coreos-profile.sh` is run.  `/etc/profile.d/coreos-profile.sh` is a symlink to `/usr/share/baselayout/coreos-profile.sh` you should be able to remove the symlink in order to disable the message.

Note that this file is also runs this code to show a list of failed units, at logon.

```
FAILED=$(systemctl list-units --state=failed --no-legend)
if [[ ! -z "${FAILED}" ]]; then
    COUNT=$(wc -l <<<"${FAILED}")
    echo -e "Failed Units: \033[31m${COUNT}\033[39m"
    awk '{ print "  " $1 }' <<<"${FAILED}"
fi
```

If this was a show stopper you could copy this functionality to some other script in `/etc/profile.d/`

You can discover quite a lot about CoreOS Container linux by looking though the baselayout repository that contains a lot of the scripts and config files https://github.com/coreos/baselayout. You can find the script in question here: https://github.com/coreos/baselayout/blob/master/baselayout/coreos-profile.sh and the config used to generate the symlink here: https://github.com/coreos/baselayout/blob/master/tmpfiles.d/baselayout-etc.conf

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding issue for this problem on github https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1968